# How do I edit Excel Spreadsheet shared over sharepoint.com using java

Tags: java, excel

At my work I have a to keep records of all the supports I have provided to the clients of our company in an Online Excel sheet. Now being a java developer I find this very boring task and it also consumes my time as same data I have to copy paste 2-3 places. Can someone please tell how can I automate this using java. 
Attached is the snapshot of my online excel sheet., we call it support tracker. 
Under Support_Tracker we have to maintain all the supports we have provided to every project.

[image]

Then right to that(SalesForce_issue_tracer, Servicenow_issue_tracker) are the products for which we provide support. Now to these products sheet, I have to copy paste the data from Support_Tracker. I want to automate all this stuuf. 
Please tell how can I achieve this. 
I google it and found some APIs, one of them is Apache POI, but I am not sure whether I can edit an Online Excel fine using this.
Excel fine is on sharePoint.com.
[image]

Comment: I never worked with that stuff, but it seems there is a [Excel Online API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) available. As long this is HTTP you should can do it with Java like [here](https://github.com/yoshioterada/Office-365-Excel-REST-API-for-Java).

Comment: Anyway, what is about to use a support ticket system and get rid of Excel ?